# Cómo cerrar un QDialog al precionar un componente dentro de él o al clickear fuera del dialog

Tags: python, pyqt

Tengo estos dos archivos:

Uno es `Dialog`, el cual posee dos clases, `SimpleDialog` y `SimpleDialogItem`.
El problema que tengo que es que deseo que el `SimpleDialog` se cierre cuando haga click fuera de éste, o cuando se presione un componente de él (`SimpleDialogItem`).

El segundo archivo es `test.py`, el cual al testear el código, resulta que `MainLayout` es un QWidget.

**Dialog.py**

```python
# coding=utf-8
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class SimpleDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, title=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Tool)
        self.setMinimumWidth(280)

        self.__inWidget = []
        self.__textColor = "#212121"

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto Medium")
        font.setPixelSize(20)

        self.__title = QLabel()
        self.__title.setFont(font)
        self.__title.setWordWrap(True)
        self.__title.hide()
        if title:
            self.setTitle(title)

        self.__vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__vLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.__vLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 8)

        textLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        textLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        textLayout.setMargin(24)
        textLayout.setSpacing(0)
        textLayout.addWidget(self.__title)

        contentLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        contentLayout.setSpacing(0)
        contentLayout.setMargin(0)
        contentLayout.addLayout(textLayout)
        contentLayout.addLayout(self.__vLayout)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        widget.setLayout(contentLayout)

        main = QVBoxLayout()
        main.setSpacing(0)
        main.setMargin(0)
        main.addWidget(widget)

        backBoard = QHBoxLayout()
        backBoard.addLayout(main)
        backBoard.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.setLayout(backBoard)

    def focusOutEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 56
        self.close()

    def addItem(self, simpleDialogItem):
        """ SimpleDialog.addItem(SimpleDialogItem)
        Agrega un item al SimpleDialog
        """
        if type(simpleDialogItem) == SimpleDialogItem:
            self.__vLayout.addWidget(simpleDialogItem)
            self.__inWidget.append(simpleDialogItem)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Se espera un SimpleDialogItem y se recibio: " + type(simpleDialogItem))

    def setTitle(self, title):
        """ SimpleDialog.setTitle(str)
        Establece el titulo del SimpleDialog
        """
        self.__title.setText(title)
        self.__title.show()


class SimpleDialogItem(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, icon=None, text=None):
        """ SimpleDialogItem(icon=path, text=str)
        Item utilizado en SimpleDialog
        """
        QPushButton.__init__(self)

        self.__text = QLabel()
        self.__text.setWordWrap(True)
        self.__text.setContentsMargins(24, 0, 24, 0)

        self.__layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__layout.addWidget(self.__text)
        self.__layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.__layout.setContentsMargins(0, 4, 0, 4)
        self.setFixedHeight(48)

        self.setLayout(self.__layout)
        if text:
            self.setText(text)

    def setText(self, text):
        """ SimpleDialogItem.setText(str)
        Establece el texto del widget
        """
        self.__text.setText(text)
```

test.py

```python
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPushButton, QDialog

from Dialog import SimpleDialog, SimpleDialogItem



class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        b = QPushButton("button")
        b.released.connect(self.hola)

        l = QHBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(b)

        self.setLayout(l)

    def hola(self):
        t = "Three line wrapped text goes here making it wrap to next line and continues longer to be here "
        tt = "You'll lose all photos and media."
        ttt = "You'll lose all photos and media."
        sd = SimpleDialog(title="Are you sure?")
        self.item = SimpleDialogItem(text=t, icon="slide_1.jpg")
        self.item.released.connect(self.chao)
        item2 = SimpleDialogItem(text=tt)
        item3 = SimpleDialogItem(text=ttt)
        sd.addItem(self.item)
        sd.addItem(item2)
        sd.addItem(item3)
        sd.exec_()

    def chao(self):
        print "Hola mundo!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.activateWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

El código no detecta `focusOut` en `SimpleDialog`. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Como te dije en el otro post, coloca solo lo necesario, hay muchas cosas que no se pueden reproducir, por ejemplo _HEXDEC

Comment: Me habia faltado añadir el _HEXDEC, explico un poco, el principal problema que tengo es que el SimpleDialogItem se supone que deberia ser detectado como un focusOutEvent en el SimpleDialog, pero por alguna razon en la forma que esta implementado no me deja utilizarlo ya que al intentar el click me sigue tomando como que esta dentro del widget. pero aun asi el focusInEvent tampoco lo toma. Podria simplificar quitando los style pero el resto es practicamente necesario. Le quitare lo necesario para que funcione si se tienen esos dos py :) ya que los colores tambien los tengo en otro archivo xD

Comment: Entiendo tu problema, pero para resolverlo necesito reproducirlo al menos, en tu caso no lo puedo hacer ya que tienes muchas cosas no definidas en tu código.

Comment: además podrías añardir MainLayout ya que usas una función llamada addView que no es parte de QWidget

Comment: Ahi lo edite y saque el MainLayout, solo es un entorno grafico basado en un QWidget  con otros metodos y atributos que hacian mas llamados xD

Comment: Esos dos permiten ejecutar ahora :) me explico nuevamente, el problema es que al mostrar o "exec_()"utar  el el SimpleDialog deseo que este se cierre cuando haga click fuera de el, o en el widget que lo llama en este caso el QDialog. De la misma forma trato que se cierre cuando se haga click en algun componente de el, especificamente los SimpleDialogItem que se añaden al padre. Pero quiero evitar tener que hacer el "self.widget.close()" al conectarlo a un metodo. Estoy tratando que sea autonomo.

Comment: el método addView() sigue generando el error

Comment: Disculpa, me falto cambiar ese addview a un setLayout

Comment: Por favor, para un proximo post corrige esos errores, sino será imposible que alguien te ayude, lee este artículo: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: y este también: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Gracias, disculpa lo sucio del codigo, es que no suelo preguntar mucho,pero revisare las reglas, reduje mas el codigo y sigue igual, mantuve el focus out ya que si clickeas en varias parte del boton no pasa pero en algun momento hace un focusOut y se ejecuta el sobre-escrito.

Comment: Prueba cambiando Qt.Tool a Qt.Popup

Comment: Ya lo intente, me genera una sombra que si intento ocultar con Wa_MacNoShadow pierde el tema del popup para cerrarse al clickear fuera. Y quedaria el tema que se cierre al hacer click en alguno de los botones internos.

Comment: En mi caso no pierde el tema, ni aparece ninguna sombra

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52137/discussion-between-christopher-vivar-vivar-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 1):

Estimados lectores, deseo mostrarles la solucion que encontré a mi problema.
 Primero, ¿como cerrar mi widget `SimpleDialog`al clickear fuera de el?
Hice una pequeña modificación al final del widget, la cual me permite ampliar este mismo y manegar toda su area.

```
main = QVBoxLayout()
main.addWidget(...contenido...)

self.fullWidget = QWidget()
self.fullWidget.setLayout(main)
self.fullWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: RGB(0,0,0,30)")

l = QHBoxLayout()
l.addWidget(self.fullWidget)

self.showFullScreen()
self.setLayout(l)
```

Así, de esta forma puedo sobre escribir el `mouseReleaseEvent` para detectar el area superior y al terminar el *click* que se cierre.

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QEvent):
    if QApplication.widgetAt(QEvent.pos()) == self.fullWidget:
        self.close()
```

Ahora, como solución a la problema de cerrar `SimpleDialog` al presionar el `SimpleDialogItem` es sobre escribir el metodo `mouseReleaseEvent` para con *QApplication* encontrar al padre y cerrarlo

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for widget in QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
        if type(widget) == SimpleDialog:
            widget.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes cambiar `Qt.Tool` a `Qt.Popup`:

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Popup)
```

Ya no es necesario implementat el método `focusOutEvent`.

Comment: El problema es que al utilizar el Qt.Popup genera un efecto de sombra el cual no puedo eliminar sin perder la accion de close al clickear fuera :/

Comment: Podrías mostrar una imagen de ese efecto, ya que no lo observo

Comment: [http://i68.tinypic.com/xojzva.png]

Comment: Estimado ya logre arreglar ese problema con el click fuera del widget principal, ahora solo me falta un punto, detectar el click en algun hijo o 'SimpleDialogItem'. estuve probando con el 'mouseReleaseEvent', el problema es que no me detecta el click primario, pero si hago click con el boton secundario (Derecho), si detecta el release. Alguna idea de como cambiar ese detalle? cuando este terminado agregare el codigo finalizado para utilidad :)

Comment: @ChristopherVivarVivar acabo de responder una pregunta, valga la redundancia, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798371/how-to-know-which-qwidget-in-a-ui-form-got-the-focus-in-pyqt/41798912?noredirect=1#comment70807781_41798912, quizas te ayude.

Comment: casi pero no, mismo detalle aunque aplieque event filter al item o al contendor pasa en banda, no detecta el focusIn en el widget. Pero el release, detecta el click derecho o el boton 3 (rueda) sin problema.